# How to position an element and make sure it moves with whatever content it's positioned in

Tags: html, css

Good Day Team.

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how I can position the h2 headings in my code to stay in place while moving with the box it's situated in[image: Refer to image attached]

What I'm trying to do is get the headings positioned at the top right corner of the box and have it fixed to that position while moving with the rest of the content.

```css
body {
            background-color: white;
        }
        
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
            color: black;
        }
        
        .box1,
        .box2,
        .box3 {
            margin-top: 10px;
            width: 300px;
            display: inline-block;
            color: black;
            border-style: solid;
            margin-left: 10px;
            background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
            padding: 1.5%;
        }
        
        .box1 span h2,
        .box2 span h2,
        .box3 span h2 {
            text-align: right;
            background-color: honeydew;
            width: 100px;
            height: 30px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            text-align: center;
        }
        /*The below has been configured for tablet view) */
        
        @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
            .box1,
            .box2 {
                width: 39%;
            }
            .box2 {
                clear: right;
            }
            .box3 {
                width: 83%;
            }
        }
        /*The below has been configured for mobile view*/
        
        @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
            .box1,
            .box2,
            .box3 {
                width: 50%;
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Assignment 2</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Menu</h1>

    <div class="box1">
        <span><h2>Chicken</h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer non sagittis ex. Aenean tempor tortor nec dui fringilla, eu elementum ligula pulvinar. Nam at aliquet felis. Aliquam rhoncus finibus neque, sed venenatis dolor efficitur
        in. Praesent ex lectus, viverra ut consequat et, congue ac urna.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
        <span><h2>Beef</h2>Donec scelerisque felis erat, eget fringilla quam molestie eget. Morbi vestibulum semper tellus, id viverra libero consequat eget. Pellentesque a nisi vel dui malesuada pharetra vel ac nisl. Etiam ut nulla lacinia, sodales mi vitae, pulvinar turpis.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="box3">
        <span><h2>Sushi</h2>Etiam maximus erat non orci consequat, quis faucibus eros vulputate. Etiam molestie sollicitudin est et commodo. Maecenas volutpat faucibus faucibus. Donec lobortis vulputate tincidunt. Duis eget odio tincidunt, vehicula diam sed, vulputate risus. Ut libero.</span>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the `<h2>` headings an absolute position with no margin, and set the top and right to zero. Then give the box containers a relative position:

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

.box1,
.box2,
.box3 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
  padding: 1.5%;
  position:relative;
  padding-top:3em;
}

.box1 span h2,
.box2 span h2,
.box3 span h2 {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: honeydew;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0;
}


/*The below has been configured for tablet view) */

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .box1,
  .box2 {
    width: 39%;
  }
  .box2 {
    clear: right;
  }
  .box3 {
    width: 83%;
  }
}


/*The below has been configured for mobile view*/

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .box1,
  .box2,
  .box3 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Menu</h1>
<div class="box1">
  <span><h2>Chicken</h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer non sagittis ex. Aenean tempor tortor nec dui fringilla, eu elementum ligula pulvinar. Nam at aliquet felis. Aliquam rhoncus finibus neque, sed venenatis dolor efficitur
        in. Praesent ex lectus, viverra ut consequat et, congue ac urna.</span>
</div>
<div class="box2">
  <span><h2>Beef</h2>Donec scelerisque felis erat, eget fringilla quam molestie eget. Morbi vestibulum semper tellus, id viverra libero consequat eget. Pellentesque a nisi vel dui malesuada pharetra vel ac nisl. Etiam ut nulla lacinia, sodales mi vitae, pulvinar turpis.</span>
</div>
<div class="box3">
  <span><h2>Sushi</h2>Etiam maximus erat non orci consequat, quis faucibus eros vulputate. Etiam molestie sollicitudin est et commodo. Maecenas volutpat faucibus faucibus. Donec lobortis vulputate tincidunt. Duis eget odio tincidunt, vehicula diam sed, vulputate risus. Ut libero.</span>
</div>
```